# constexpr constructor's parameter type 'std::function' is not a literal type

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, constexpr, constexpr-function

I'm writting a simple C++ HTTP server framework. In my `Server` class, I can add `Route`'s. Every route consists of a path, an HTTP method and a `Controller` (which is a pipeline of functions to be called when the request was made.) That `Controller` class is constructed by receiving a list of `std::function`'s (or, more precisely: `std::function<void(const HTTPRequest&, HTTPResponse&, Context&)>`), but most of the time (or I should say *every* time), this `Controller` will be initialized with a list of lambda function literals, as in the following code:

```
server.add_route("/", HTTPMethod::GET,
                {
                    [](auto, auto& response, auto&) {
                        const int ok  = 200;
                        response.set_status(ok);
                        response << "[{ \"test1\": \"1\" },";
                        response["Content-Type"] = "text/json; charset=utf-8";
                    },
                    [](auto, auto& response, auto&) {
                        response << "{ \"test2\": \"2\" }]";
                    },
                }
        );
```

Being this the case, I would like to make the `add_route` function a `constexpr`, because, correct me if I am wrong, `constexpr` functions can be executed at compile time.

So, when I was making everything `constexpr`, I found the following error:

```
Controller.cpp:9:1 constexpr constructor's 1st parameter type 'Callable' (aka 'function<void (const HTTPRequest &, HTTPResponse &, Context &)>') is not a literal type
```

What I want to know is: why `std::function`'s can't be literal types? Is there any way to circumvent this limitation?

Below is the code for `Controller` class. I'm aware that there are still other compile errors, but this is the main issue I'm tackling right now. Thanks in advance!

`controller.hpp`

```
#pragma once

#include <functional>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>

#include "context.hpp"
#include "httprequest.hpp"
#include "httpresponse.hpp"

typedef std::function<void(const HTTPRequest&, HTTPResponse&, Context&)> Callable;
template <size_t N>
class Controller {
private:
    std::array<Callable, N> callables;

public:
    static auto empty_controller() -> Controller<1>;

    constexpr explicit Controller(Callable);
    constexpr Controller();
    constexpr Controller(std::initializer_list<Callable>);

    void call(const HTTPRequest&, HTTPResponse&, Context&);
};
```

`controller.cpp`

```
#include "controller.hpp"

template <size_t N>
auto Controller<N>::empty_controller() -> Controller<1> {
    return Controller<1>([](auto, auto, auto) {});
}

template <>
constexpr Controller<1>::Controller(Callable _callable) :
    callables(std::array<Callable, 1> { std::move(_callable) }) { }

template <>
constexpr Controller<1>::Controller() :
    Controller(empty_controller()) { }


template <size_t N>
constexpr Controller<N>::Controller(std::initializer_list<Callable> _list_callables) :
    callables(_list_callables) { }

template <size_t N>
void Controller<N>::call(const HTTPRequest& req, HTTPResponse& res, Context& ctx) {
    for (auto& callable : callables) {
        callable(req, res, ctx);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, `std::function` is not a literal type. e.g. it has no `constexpr` constructors. Perhaps you could pass a function pointer instead, which should work.

Comment: I considered to use function pointers at first, but then I found out they wouldn't allow me to make the `add_route` syntax look as clean as I have managed to make. Aside from that, as I discovered from the accepted answer, making `add_route` `constexpr` probably wouldn't even be possible, or likely wouldn't be an useful optimization, since the method necessarily has to alter the state of the `Server` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why std::function's can't be literal types? Is there any way to circumvent this limitation?

Because it uses type erasure in order to accept any callable. This requires polymorphism which cannot be constexpr until C++20 which will allow `constexpr virtual`.
You could use templates and capture the callable directly, but its type will creep into `Controller` and spread further.

> Being this the case, I would like to make the add_route function a constexpr, because, correct me if I am wrong, constexpr functions can be executed at compile time.

Yes, **if given** `constexpr` arguments, the function will be executed at compile-time. Look at it like advanced constant folding. Furthermore `constexpr` methods used in compile-time context either cannot access `*this` or it has too be constexpr. In particular, `constexpr` method can only change the state of `constexpr` instance at compile time. Otherwise the function is run ordinarly at runtime.

The last point is relevant to you, running a HTTP server at compile-time hardly makes sense, so `constexpr` is probably not needed and it won't help anything.

#### EDIT `constexpr` behaviour example

```cpp
struct Foo{
    //If all members are trivial enough and initialized, the constructor is constexpr by default.
    int state=10;
    //constexpr Foo()=default;
constexpr int bar(bool use_state){
    if(use_state)
        return state++;
    else
        return 0;// Literal
}
constexpr int get_state()const{
    return state;
}
};

template<int arg>
void baz(){}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   Foo foo;
   //Carefull, this also implies const and ::bar() is non-const.
   constexpr Foo c_foo;

   foo.bar(true);//Run-time, `this` is not constexpr even though `true` is
   foo.bar(false);//Compile-time, `this` was not needed, `false` is constexpr

   bool* b = new bool{false};
   foo.bar(*b);//Always run-time since `*b` is not constexpr



   //Force compile-time evaluation in compile-time context
   //Foo has constexpr constructor, creates non-const (temporary) constexpr instance
   baz<Foo().bar(true)>();
   baz<Foo().bar(false)>();
   baz<foo.bar(false)>();
   //ERROR, foo is not constexpr
   //baz<foo.bar(true)>();
   //ERROR, c_foo is const
   //baz<c_foo.bar(false)>();
   //Okay, c_foo is constexpr
   baz<c_foo.get_state()>();
   //ERROR, foo is not constexpr
   //baz<foo.get_state()>();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So even though every parameter inside `add_route` is a `constexpr`, the compiler wouldn't allow me to add the `constexpr` specifier for that method just because it needs to modify the state of the `Server` object?

Comment: @AndréWinston It always allows adding it, it will just fallback to run-time execution on call. The key idea is that `constexpr` forces compile-time execution **only if supplied with constexpr arguments or in compile-time context(where the arguments are also constexpr)**. It does not forbid deferring the execution to run-time as usual. The state access is on need-to-know basis. I.e. accessing state in not-taken branch is still okay even in compile-time call. I added an example to my answer. Feel free to ask for more :)

Comment: If you are interested, look at C++20 `consteval` which always runs at compile-time.